# Does Turtwig's evolutions count towards Celebi's research quest?

Tags: pokemon-go

I fairly recently started playing Pokémon Go again, and I am in the middle of the Celebi research quest. It says I need to evolve an already evolved grass creature.

[This website](https://gamerant.com/pokemon-go-evolved-grass-type-pokemon/) lists the possibilities, but I have a type called Turtwig -> Grotle-> ?? that is grass, but it's not listed. Does that mean it won't count if I evolve it again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Niantic responded to my inquiry, and this is by design. Generation 4 evolutions will not work for Celebi's Special Research.

> You need to evolve an already evolved Grass-Type Pokémon from the Kanto, Johto or Hoenn region. Please excuse the circumstances that have been caused. Unfortunately, Pokémon from the Sinnoh region do not work. 
>   <sub>(Response from Niantic support)</sub>

---

Apparently, users on reddit ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/9ppjch/evolving_grotle_doesnt_count_for_the_celebi_quest/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/9qcccx/torterra_doesnt_count_for_28_celebi_research/)) are reporting that evolving Grotle into Toterra does **not** count towards Celebi's research quest.

<strike>There have been [known issues](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001897088-Cannot-complete-certain-tasks-in-the-Celebi-Special-Research) in the past with Celebi's field research. Given that Grotle is Gen4 and was released after Celebi's field research, the consensus between the two threads is that this is likely due to a bug.</strike>

I reached out to Niantic in regards to this, and will update my answer when I hear back.